# Android split string with regex

Tags: android, regex

I have string with JSON structure like this

`String response = "{'success':1,'error_code':0,'message':'Access granted'}"`

I want to split that using String.split() to be like this:

`{[success],[1],[error_code],[0],[message],[Access Granted]}`

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13384496/1533670), [this solution too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17787132/1533670), but none of solution fit with my need.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to split a valid JSON using String.split()?

Comment: @SeshuVinay its not a JSON, its string like JSON format.

Comment: If it's LIKE a JSON string, you can treat it as a JSON string.

Comment: @M42 okay, but how? give me a link or something.

Comment: JSONObject json=new JSONObject(string);

Comment: And I would like to know who is API developer. What is success=1 message=access granted? He could give you http status code as 200 or 401?

Comment: @SeshuVinay is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
try{
   JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject("{\"success\":1,\"error_code\":0,\"message\":\"Access granted\"}");
   String valu1 = responseJson.getString("success");
   String valu2 = responseJson.getString("error_code");
   String valu3 = responseJson.getString("message");
}catch (Throwable e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: And what about a comma in the value like: `"message":"Access, granted"`

Comment: @M42,is this kind of requirement his ask ?

Comment: I've updated my question, i think your response string was wrong. I need from `String response = "{'success':1,'error_code':0,'message':'Access granted'}"`

Comment: Not asked here but it may occur.